# Servicestack REDIS CacheClient failing with password

Tags: redis, servicestack

I am moving a system towards production, part of this has involved changing the REDIS server used for authentication caching, from a service running on a dev box to a more suitable environment.  The new box(es) are a pair (for now) configured as master and slave **with a password**

My code for connecting up to REDIS followed the standard pattern:

```
  container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));
  container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => (ICacheClient)c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
```

For the new box I have modified this to:

```
string[] ReadWriteHosts = new[] {
        "XYZ@10.10.10.10:6379"
        };

string[] ReadOnlyHosts = new[] {
        "XYZ@10.10.10.11:6379"
        };

var REDISClientManager = new PooledRedisClientManager(ReadWriteHosts, ReadOnlyHosts);
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(REDISClientManager);
container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => (ICacheClient)c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
```

When I fire the app up and try to login in I receive:

```
'base.UserSession' threw an exception of type 'ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException'

"Client sent AUTH, but no password is set, sPort: 0, LastCommand: "
```

I've not managed to follow it all the way through yet, just wondered if anybody could see anything obviously wrong.